# The last page of pageViewController performs a segue without being asked

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I have a page view controller consisting of several view controllers. I want to achieve that when it comes to the last page of the page view controller and the user slides it, it can go to another view controller.

Below is my code in method `viewControllerAfterViewController`:

```
-(UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSString *vcRestorationID = viewController.restorationIdentifier;
    NSUInteger index = [self.contentPageRestorationIDs indexOfObject:vcRestorationID];
    if (index==self.contentPageRestorationIDs.count-1) {
        if ([_source isEqual:@"HelpViewController"]) {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toHelp" sender:self];
        }
        else if ([_source isEqual:@"ViewController"]){
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toMain" sender:self];
        }
         //return nil;
    }
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index+1];
}
```

I thought the `viewControllerAfterViewController` is being called when I slide the pages in the pageViewController. My problem now is, when it comes to the last page, sometimes it would just perform the segue without being slide, but sometimes it can work normally and perform the segue after I slide it. And I don't know when it would work as I expect.

I wonder why would that happen? Is there a way to solve it?

Comment: `viewControllerAfterViewController` shouldn't perform any segues. It just should return `UIViewController`

Comment: @Cy-4AH Is there a way that I can achieve what I expect? Could you please give me some suggestions?